# Users are getting "Help Us Protect your account" even that we have disabled MFA

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, sharepoint-online, multi-factor-authentication

We have disabled MFA for our users, as follow:-

[image]

but still when the users try to access the Office 365 they get this message:-

[image]

any advice? we need to remove this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [disable security defaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults#disabling-security-defaults) which is automatically enabled for tenants created after October 22, 2019. Security defaults are a number of pre-enabled security settings, mostly around MFA, including requiring all users to register for MFA.

Note the other settings that are impacted by disabling this

- Requiring all users to register for Azure AD Multi-Factor Authentication.
- Requiring administrators to do multi-factor authentication.
- Requiring users to do multi-factor authentication when necessary.
- Blocking legacy authentication protocols.
- Protecting privileged activities like access to the Azure portal.